# In Magento 2 how to create product (4 products @499)

Tags: categories, product, magento2.1

In magento 2 I got a client requirement, is that 4 product will be sale @599. How can I implement 4product@499 in magento 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like:

- If you buy 1 of Product-A they are 599 each.
- If you buy 4 of Product-A they are 499 each.

If so you want to use Magento's teir pricing functionality detailed here: http://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/catalog/product-price-tier.html